# how do I get Add and Sum by column index value in Google Spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet, say it's called `raw sheet` like this:

```
Column Index | A | B  |
David        | 1 | 10 |
Jerry        | 5 | 15 |
David        | 1 | 50 |
Jerry        | 6 | 20 |
David        | 8 | 20 |
```

There are only limited values in Column Index. Like in this case only "David" and "Jerry".

I want to create another sheet, say it's called `summary sheet` that can summarize some value by the Column Index value, like this:

```
Column Index Summary | f(A,B)     |
David                | some value |
Jerry                | some value |
```

The f(A,B) can be any kind of function that take use of all the values in the first sheet. One example: to add every row's A*B to get a new number. In this case, it would be:

```
Column Index Summary | f(A,B)     |
David                | 220        | that is 1*10 + 1*50 + 8*20
Jerry                | 195        | that is 5*15 + 6*20
```

What should I do?

Comment: A pivot table and you can make use of custom formulae to get the function you're looking for (btw, you don't have custom formulae in GSpreadsheet)

Comment: @Jerry - Could you explain:  _(btw, you don't have custom formulae in GSpreadsheet)_?

Comment: @Mogsdad AFAIK, you cannot define the formulas in excel's pivot table besides the standard operations like sum, count, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Google Sheets custom function for you. It will operate on any arbitrary table of numerical data, aggregating the numbers by any arbitrary (but simple) algebraic expression. (Expression must be valid in Javascript, e.g. `"A * B"`, `"A + B / C"`, or even `"Math.pow(A,B)"`.) There's no error checking, so it's not fool-proof.

Examples:

`=summary('raw sheet'!A1:C6,"A*B")` Yes, you can refer to different sheets.

[image: screenshot]

`=summary(A1:C6,"A*A + B")`

[image: screenshot]

`=summary(A1:C6,"Math.pow(A,B)")`

[image: screenshot]

#### Custom Function

```
/**
 * Performs given formula on each row in table, aggregating (summing)
 * row results by the key value in first column.
 *
 * See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925283/how-do-i-get-add-and-sum-by-column-index-value-in-google-spreasheet/26942156#26942156
 *
 * @param {range} table     Input data table, including headers
 * @param {string} formula  Mathematical function to peform on each
 *                          row in table, using header values as
 *                          function parameters.
 * @param {int} sortType    (Optional, default 1) 0: do not sort, 1: sort ascending, -1: sort descending
 * @param {int} sortColumn  (Optional, default 1) Column to sort by.
 *
 * @return {range}          Summary table of results
 * @customfunction
 */
function summary(table,formula,sortType,sortColumn) {
  sortType = (sortType == undefined) ? 1 : sortType;
  sortColumn = (sortColumn == undefined) ? 1 : sortColumn;

  // Sort comparison function for ordering summary table
  // uses sortType & sortColumn
  function colCompare(a,b) 
  {
    var col = sortColumn - 1;
    var order = sortType;
    if (!order) return 1;
    else 
    return ((a[col] < b[col]) ? -order : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? order : 0));
  }

  var headers = table[0];

  // Start results with its header row
  var summaryTable = [[headers[0],String(formula)]];

  // evaluate formula, replacing variables (headers) with references to table
  for (var h = 1; h < headers.length; h++) {
    var re = new RegExp(headers[h],"g");
    formula = formula.replace( re, " table[row]["+parseInt(h)+"] " );
  }

  // Aggregate data by summing formula for each row
  var summary = {};
  for (var row=1; row<table.length; row++) {
    var key = table[row][0];
    if (!(key in summary))
      summary[key] = 0;
    summary[key] += eval( formula );
  }

  // Append aggregated rows to results, and return
  for (key in summary) {
    summaryTable.push([key,summary[key]]);
  }

  // Sort the results
  headers = summaryTable.splice(0, 1);
  summaryTable.sort(colCompare).unshift(headers[0]);
  return summaryTable;
}
```

**EDIT:** Nov 17 - added sort functionality

Comment: What should I do if I want to sort the summary table by its calculated value? Thanks!

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo- Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for how to sort arrays. It can be tricky, when there are "header" rows. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: One more question, what if I want to specify specified color to specified conditioned cells? Like, if the summary column is greater than 0, make the cell and its left cell (that would be the name like "David" or "Jerry") to become red. And if less than 0, make them green.

Comment: You might be able to just use advanced [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) over the range, with a custom formula. Otherwise, ask this as a separate question, but refer back to this one so people can have some context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the names in Col A and the col A of the example is actually Col B,
in the summary sheet, try something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({'raw sheet'!A2:A,'raw sheet'!B2:B*'raw sheet'!C2:C}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group By Col1 label sum(Col2) 'TOTAL' "))
```