# How to get SUM and AVERAGE using google apps script instead of using formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have spreadsheet containing score, I am using formula to get value SUM (=SUM(C2:E2)) and AVERAGE (=AVERAGE(C2:E2)), my question is how to get SUM and AVERAGE using Google Apps Script?

[spreadsheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBNtx.png)

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26925283/1595451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this through scripts rather than the build-in formulas, but this is a solution that should work.

#### Code

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sumAve');
  // range is from row 2, column 3 (C) all the way down to the last row with data and 3 columns wide
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();

  // counter starts at 2 because row 1 is headers
  let counter = 2;

  for (const row of range) {
    const sum = row.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    // column 8 and 9
    sheet.getRange(counter, 8).setValue(sum)
    sheet.getRange(counter, 9).setValue(sum / row.length)
    counter++;
  }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Out of curiosity, why would you prefer a script rather than a formula?